# how to install pymssql package under unix?

Tags: python, unix, pymssql

Please help me how to install pymssql under unix while the server has no internet connection. I tried to download file with extension .egg (pymssql-2.0.1-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg) but i dont know to install it.

should i copy it to python directory /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to unzip that package in some install folder, go to that folder and type

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

After that, you may even remove that install folder, it's not longer needed.

Details : http://pymssql.org/building_and_developing.html